# What is sys.maxint in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to find out how to represent a maximum integer, and I've read to use `"sys.maxint"`. However, in Python 3 when I call it I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'object' has no attribute 'maxint'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

> The `sys.maxint` constant was removed, since there is no longer a limit to the value of integers. However, [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) can be used as an integer larger than any practical list or string index. It conforms to the implementation’s “natural” integer size and is typically the same as `sys.maxint` in previous releases on the same platform (assuming the same build options).

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Comment: That's all nice and good, until you need a timedelta(days=x) and x is larger than 2^32: then you get OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int.

Comment: @marcotama `datetime.timedelta` can only go up to `days=999_999_999` anyway. You should probably use a different library.

Answer (score 104):

As pointed out by others, Python 3's `int` does not have a maximum size, but if you just need something that's guaranteed to be higher than any other `int` value, then you can use the float value for Infinity, which you can get with `float("inf")`.

In Python 3.5 onwards, you can use [`math.inf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.inf).

Note: as per ely's comment, this may impact the efficiency of your code, so it may not be the best solution.

Comment: Also works with legacy Python (2.7) - this is the correct answer when you need to return a number higher than all possible real values (e.g. for list sorting by comparing objects)

Comment: One downside of this approach is that float inf can ruin the data type of arrays if you are trying to apply jit compilation with numba or Cython or similar. You may need a Python list of all integer types so that a jit compiler can automatically convert it to the appropriate c type, for example. This is especially critical for classical algorithms where you might apply jit tools to make them much faster than a pure Python implementation, but still want to write the implementation in pure Python for convenience, testing, fallback if jit compiler is not installed in a deployed environment, etc.

Answer (score 43):

If you are looking for a number that is bigger than all others:

Method 1:

```
float('inf')
```

Method 2:

```
import sys
max = sys.maxsize
```

If you are looking for a number that is smaller than all others:

Method 1:

```
float('-inf')
```

Method 2:

```
import sys
min = -sys.maxsize - 1
```

Method 1 works in both Python2 and Python3. Method 2 works in Python3. I have not tried Method 2 in Python2.

Comment: Hi sys.maxsize only returns 9223372036854775807 this, if your number goes greater than that it return False (ie) your_large_no<sys.maxsize  will return False

Comment: …Please use `math.inf` and `-math.inf` instead of parsing a string.

Comment: It is ok to use either math.inf or 'inf'

Comment: It is a little shorter, a little clearer and a tiny bit faster - one less function call - to use `math.inf` over `float('inf')`

Answer (score 32):

Python 3 ints do not have a maximum.

If your purpose is to determine the maximum size of an int in C when compiled the same way Python was, you can use the struct module to find out:

```
>>> import struct
>>> platform_c_maxint = 2 ** (struct.Struct('i').size * 8 - 1) - 1
```

If you are curious about the internal implementation details of Python 3 int objects, Look at `sys.int_info` for bits per digit and digit size details. No normal program should care about these.

Comment: Note that a python 2 int was the equivilent of a C long, not a C int.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.0 doesn't have sys.maxint any more since Python 3's ints are of
arbitrary length. Instead of sys.maxint it has sys.maxsize; the maximum
size of a positive sized size_t aka Py_ssize_t.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is

```py
import math

... math.inf ...
```