# _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)

Tags: python, csv

I have a script reading in a csv file with very huge fields:

```
# example from http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv%20dictreader#examples
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

However, this throws the following error on some csv files:

```
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

How can I analyze csv files with huge fields? Skipping the lines with huge fields is not an option as the data needs to be analyzed in subsequent steps.

Comment: Even better would be to consider _why_ there are such big fields  Is that expected in your data? Sometimes errors like these are indicative of a different problem.  I had some Bad Data in mine that included a random double quote character and thus had to use the QUOTE_NONE option shown in another answer here.

Comment: I updated my question to indicate that in my case huge fields might occur. There is no bad data in the csv file.

Comment: @dustmachine Such things happen because sometimes you find people storing images (or other binary files) in base64 format in database tables.

Answer (score 508, accepted):

The csv file might contain very huge fields, therefore increase the `field_size_limit`:

```
import sys
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
```

`sys.maxsize` works for Python 2.x and 3.x. `sys.maxint` would only work with Python 2.x ([SO: what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3))

#### Update

As Geoff pointed out, the code above might result in the following error: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`. 
To circumvent this, you could use the following *quick and dirty* code (which should work on every system with Python 2 and Python 3):

```
import sys
import csv
maxInt = sys.maxsize

while True:
    # decrease the maxInt value by factor 10 
    # as long as the OverflowError occurs.

    try:
        csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
        break
    except OverflowError:
        maxInt = int(maxInt/10)
```

Comment: On Windows 7 64bit with Python 2.6, `maxInt = sys.maxsize` returns `9223372036854775807L` which consequently results in a `TypeError: limit must be an integer` when calling `csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)`. Interestingly, using `maxInt = int(sys.maxsize)` does not change this. A crude workaround is to simlpy use `csv.field_size_limit(2147483647)` which of course cause issues on other platforms. In my case this was adquat to identify the broken value in the CSV, fix the export options in the other application and remove the need for  `csv.field_size_limit()`.

Answer (score 192):

This could be because your CSV file has embedded single or double quotes. If your CSV file is tab-delimited try opening it as:

```
c = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Thank you!!  If you are using csvkit (an excellent python library and command-line csv toolkit) and get the original error because your file uses unbalanced single or double quotes, you can select QUOTE_NONE via the `-u 3` command line option, aka `--quoting 3`

Comment: I had the error `field larger than field limit` because of a single double-quote in a bad formatted CSV file.

Comment: THAT was the root cause in my case, good job catching it!

Answer (score 57):

*.csv* field sizes are controlled via [[Python.Docs]: csv.field_size_limit([new_limit])](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.field_size_limit) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Returns the current maximum field size allowed by the parser. **If *new_limit* is given, this becomes the new limit**.

It is set by default to ***131072*** or ***0x20000*** (*128k*), which should be enough for any decent *.csv*:

> ```py
> >>> import csv
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> limit0 = csv.field_size_limit()
> >>> limit0
> 131072
> >>> "0x{0:016X}".format(limit0)
> '0x0000000000020000'
> ```

However, when dealing with a *.csv* file (**with the correct quoting and delimiter**) having (at least) one field longer than this size, the error pops up. 
To get rid of the error, the size limit should be increased (to avoid any worries, the maximum possible value is attempted).

Behind the scenes (check [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (master) cpython/Modules/_csv.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_csv.c) for implementation details), the variable that holds this value is a *C **long*** ([[Wikipedia]: C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)), whose size **varies depending on *CPU* architecture and *OS*** (*I**L**P*). The classical difference: for a ***064bit*** *OS* (and *Python* build), the *long* type size (**in bits**) is:

- *Nix*: ***64***
- *Win*: ***32***

When attempting to set it, the new value is checked to be in the *long* boundaries, that's why in some cases another exception pops up (because *sys.maxsize* is typically *064bit* wide - encountered on *Win*):

> ```py
> >>> import sys, ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> "v{:d}.{:d}.{:d}".format(*sys.version_info[:3]), sys.platform, sys.maxsize, ct.sizeof(ct.c_void_p) * 8, ct.sizeof(ct.c_long) * 8
> ('v3.9.9', 'win32', 9223372036854775807, 64, 32)
> >>>
> >>> csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
> ```

To avoid running into this problem, set the (maximum possible) limit (***LONG_MAX***), **using an artifice** (thanks to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)). It should work on *Python 3* and *Python 2*, on any *CPU* / *OS*.

> ```py
> >>> csv.field_size_limit(int(ct.c_ulong(-1).value // 2))
> 131072
> >>> limit1 = csv.field_size_limit()
> >>> limit1
> 2147483647
> >>> "0x{0:016X}".format(limit1)
> '0x000000007FFFFFFF'
> ```

*064bit* *Python* on a *Nix* like *OS*:

> ```py
> >>> import sys, csv, ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> "v{:d}.{:d}.{:d}".format(*sys.version_info[:3]), sys.platform, sys.maxsize, ct.sizeof(ct.c_void_p) * 8, ct.sizeof(ct.c_long) * 8
> ('v3.8.10', 'linux', 9223372036854775807, 64, 64)
> >>>
> >>> csv.field_size_limit()
> 131072
> >>>
> >>> csv.field_size_limit(int(ct.c_ulong(-1).value // 2))
> 131072
> >>> limit1 = csv.field_size_limit()
> >>> limit1
> 9223372036854775807
> >>> "0x{0:016X}".format(limit1)
> '0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'
> ```

For *032bit* *Python*, things should run smoothly without the artifice (as both *sys.maxsize* and *LONG_MAX* are *032bit* wide). 
If this maximum value is still not enough, then the *.csv* would need manual intervention in order to be processed from *Python*.

Check the following resources for more details on:

- Playing with *C* types boundaries from *Python*: [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546)
- *Python* *064bit* *vs* *032bit* differences: [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546)

Answer (score 42):

Below is to check the current limit

```
csv.field_size_limit()
```

Out[20]: 131072

Below is to increase the limit. Add it to the code

```
csv.field_size_limit(100000000)
```

Try checking the limit again

```
csv.field_size_limit()
```

Out[22]: 100000000

Now you won't get the error "_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)"

Comment: Simple solution, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I just had this happen to me on a 'plain' CSV file. Some people might call it an invalid formatted file. No escape characters, no double quotes and delimiter was a semicolon.

A sample line from this file would look like this:

> First cell; Second " Cell with one double quote and leading
>   space;'Partially quoted' cell;Last cell

the single quote in the second cell would throw the parser off its rails. What worked was:

```
csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=';', doublequote='False', quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: `doublequote` is ignored when `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`

Comment: @2Toad that is interesting to know. I thought I needed to specify both, but maybe I never tried `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` before adding `quotechar=''`and `doublequote='False'`. Gonna dig a bit on this during the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, a row contain double quote column. When csv reader try read this row, not understood end of column and fire this raise.
Solution is below:

```
reader = csv.reader(cf, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `error_bad_lines` option of `pd.read_csv` to skip these lines.

```py
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This works since the "bad lines" as defined in pandas include lines that one of their fields exceed the csv limit.

Be careful that this solution is valid only when the fields in your csv file *shouldn't* be this long.
If you expect to have big field sizes, this will throw away your data.

Comment: There is no bad line ... as written in the question: The csv files contains huge fields and this data need to be analyzed.

Comment: *Bad lines* concept in `pandas` includes the rows which exceed the field limit of `csv`. So, if you want to skip these lines and read other lines successfully, you may use this solution. Otherwise, when huge fields are required for you, increasing field limit by `csv.field_size_limit(100000000)` is appropriate.

Comment: You should explain why you use `error_bad_lines`

Answer (score -3):

Find the cqlshrc file usually placed in .cassandra directory.

In that file append,

```
[csv]
field_size_limit = 1000000000
```

Comment: entities should not be multiplied without necessity

Comment: There is no Cassandra here. This would be a suitable answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168235/cassandra-cqlsh-text-field-limit-on-copy-from-csv-field-larger-than-field-limit