# file larger than field limit with Hcatalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I'm working in standalone (our cluster is not configured yet). I try to create a new table from a file with HCatalog, but I have the following error.

`field larger than field limit (131072)`

This value seems to be the value of the `io.file.buffer.size`, which is configured to 131072. Am I right? But, the description for this option is  `Size of read/write buffer used in SequenceFiles`, so I'm not sure at all. My file is a text file. So I'm not sure, this is the good property to change.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's either because,

1. Your field delimiter set in Hive create statement is not set to a right one, so field read in buffer exceeded maximum allowed length.
2. Your field delimiter is set right, but some field is really long, or missing the right delimiter. If that's the case, you need somehow pre-process the file to make sure it won't have such cases.

A similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063936/csv-error-field-larger-than-field-limit-131072)