# Cassandra CQLSH TEXT field limit on COPY FROM CSV (field larger than field limit (131072))

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When importing a record with a large field inside (longer than 124214 characters) I am getting the error

> "field larger than field limit (131072)"

I saw form other posts how to solve this on Python but I don't know if it is possible on CQLSH.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:

[_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063936/csv-error-field-larger-than-field-limit-131072)

You will need to add this solution to the top of the cqlsh file. So after:

```
import csv
import getpass

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? In which cqlsh file should I add those lines?

Comment: @ashwinator cassandra/bin/cqlsh

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention earlier, I use ubuntu. Where would be the file?

Answer (score 17):

Rather than hacking into the cqlsh file, there is a standard option provided by cassandra to change the `field_size_limit`. The Cassandra installation includes a `cqlshrc.sample` file in the conf directory of a tarball distribution. In this file the `field_size_limit` option can be found and changed. To make cqlsh read it's options from this file, you need to copy the `cqlshrc.sample` file from the conf directory to the hidden `.cassandra` folder of your user home folder, and renaming it to cqlshrc.

Cassandra documentation contains more details about it: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html?scroll=refCqlsh__cqlshUsingCqlshrc

Comment: Direct link to cqlshrc documentation here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshrc.html

Answer (score 2):

Download & extract the cassandra distribution from
https://cassandra.apache.org/download/

You will find cqlshrc.sample file in conf directory after you extracted

Copy the cqlshrc.sample to ~/.cassandra and rename it to cqlshrc

Open the cqlshrc file and change `; field_size_limit = 131072` to `field_size_limit = 1000000000`

Don't forget to remove ";" in the above step

Open a new terminal & run your queries