# Cassandra cql copy error field larger than field limit

Tags: cassandra, copy, limit, cql

I am using Cassandra 3.11.3.
And when I want to import from a CSV file, I encounter the

> Error - field larger than field limit (131072), given up after 1 attempts

I have tried the solutions of [this (now deleted) link of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168235/cassandra-cqlsh-text-field-limit-on-copy-from-csv-field-larger-than-field-limit/53517332#53517332), but the problem persists.

Comment: What did you try already? Setting of `field_size_limit` in `cqlshrc` didn't help? Can you show content of that file?

Comment: Yes, I have set field_size_limit in cqlshrc file (in home_directory/.cassandra/) and it doesn't help. here is the change that I have made to this  file:  
[csv]
;; The size limit for parsed fields
; field_size_limit = 1048576

Comment: please insert the content in your post (use `edit` link) - I can't understand real content. I see the `;` before `field_size_limit` - if it's on the same line, then you need to remove everything before `field_size_limit` because the `;` is comment character