# numpy.dot giving incorrect answer for large integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I'm working on some linear algebra stuff, and simply can't figure out why `numpy` gives the following:

[image]

The result I got from mathematica, and by hand is

[image]

**Edit**: If you need the matrices:

```
test = [[19722145, -21016468, 51417377],
        [-185674670, 298847128, -428429486],
        [289326728, -516012704, 691212936]]

A = [[9, 4, 1], [2, 0, 8], [-8, 8, -8]]
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50671172/edit) your question with arrays & code as text, not images.

Comment: I tried copying your data but sadly I can't copy text in images.

Comment: try `dtype` `int64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @PaulPanzer, you need to use `np.int64` dtype arrays. NumPy uses `np.int32` for your input arrays *on your platform / system configuration*<sup>1</sup> and does not check for integer overflow.

However, the result of your matrix multiplication includes integers which are too large to be stored in `np.int32`.

Since NumPy doesn't automatically upcast the input arrays to `np.int64`, you need to specify `np.int64` explicitly, either when you define the array or via upcasting:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([[19722145, -21016468, 51417377],
                 [-185674670, 298847128, -428429486],
                 [289326728, -516012704, 691212936]],
                dtype=np.int64)

A = np.array([[9, 4, 1],
              [2, 0, 8],
              [-8, 8, -8]],
             dtype=np.int64)

res = np.dot(test, A)

print(res)

[[ -275872647   490227596  -559748615]
 [ 2354058114 -4170134568  5632538242]
 [-3957788344  6687010400 -9368478392]]
```

<sup>1</sup> Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774047/using-numpy-to-square-value-gives-negative-number). There's also been some [discussion on platform-specific issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine).

Comment: Thank you so much, such a noob mistake haha

Comment: Whether `numpy` uses `int32` or `int64` will depend on the OS and computer.  Mine, a recent Linux on refurbished desktop uses `int64` as default.