# get db values from .wav file python

Tags: python, wav, decibel

I am trying to get db values from .wav file python using this formula:
`dbs = [20 * np.log10(np.sqrt(np.mean(chunk ** 2))) for chunk in chunks]`
The issue I am facing is I am getting `NaN` values in `dbs` list because of negative values coming from `np.mean(chunk**2)`.
How can I resole this issue?

Comment: The logarithm of a negative number is undefined, and the `nan` is because of this. you can map negative values of `np.mean(chunk ** 2)` to 1 so its `log10` will be 0.

Comment: isn't that np.mean(chunk ** 2) return positive? because we are squaring.

Comment: Oh actually you are right, but I was confused with your statement where you say: `The issue I am facing is I am getting NaN values in dbs list because of negative values coming from np.mean(chunk**2).`

Comment: the Issue is I am getting nan values from formula(dbs) because np.mean(chunk**2) returning negative numbers I am trying to find why it's returning negative values and how to resolve it.

Comment: Check for overflows. Deos this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774113/8961170

Comment: yes. it working now.