# Numpy overflow warning when when subtracting 1 from 2**31 but not from numpy.power(2,31) when storing the results in int32

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

This might be a little nitty gritty, but I would like to know this behavior of Numpy in more detail (numpy version 1.26.3).

I encountered this when programming a simple Park and Miller random number generator. It involves calculating the modulus with 2^31-1 and just happened to define it exactly like that:

```
m = numpy.power(2,31)-1
```

and got a warning `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar subtract m = numpy.power(2,31)-1`. I was slightly surprised at first, but I quickly realized that numpy works with int32 by default, even in 64-bit machines. But that got me wondering why there was no error on the power, which overflows the signed 32-bit integer. The result is still correct:

```
print(type(m),m)

<class 'numpy.int32'> 2147483647
```

Direct storage of 2147483648 to m gives overflow error `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`.

This worked well; I got a warning now that I was storing 2^31-1. If I had instead stored 2^31, I would have got a wrong answer without warning:

```
test = np.power(2,31)
print(type(test),test)

<class 'numpy.int32'> -2147483648
```

Instead of the correct answer, `2147483648`. Is there a guideline on when to carefully check for this kind of behavior with Numpy?

Comment: An old bug issue regarding integer overflow warnings in numpy, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987.  I think it still applies.

Comment: one of many possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774047/using-numpy-to-square-value-gives-negative-number

Comment: I was almost sure that I was not the first one wondering. Just couldn't catch that old question from the top 20 google results. Thanx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using numpy to square value gives negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774047/using-numpy-to-square-value-gives-negative-number)