# A bug of Python's power operator **?

Tags: python, numpy

From the following code:

```
import numpy as np

print 2**np.array([32, 33])
```

I get the negative numbers `[-2147483648 -2147483648]`. I'm using python 2.6. Is it some sort of bug? On the contrary `print 2**32` gives the correct answer `4294967296`.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows, but I'm not sure it is overflow. When I write print 2**32 I get  4294967296

Comment: May I ask why a bug in a built-in operator was your first guess?

Comment: Doing plain `2**32` gives the right result because it's using Python integers, which can grow arbitrarily large (although in Python 2 integers that are larger than the CPU native integer size will be `long` rather than `int`) . But Numpy is designed to use fixed sized numbers, not Python integers.

Comment: @MYGz Even with 64-bit Windows that can be an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36279549/2285236

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These values are too big to store in a `32-bit int` which `numpy` uses by default. If you set the datatype to `float` (or `64-bit int`) you get the proper results:

```
import numpy as np

print 2 ** np.array([32, 33], dtype=np.float)
# [  4.2946730e+09  8.58993459e+09  ]

print 2 ** np.array([32, 33], dtype=np.int64) # 64-bit int as suggested by PM 2Ring
# [  4294967296  8589934592]
```

Comment: Or if you want exact integer results use `dtype=np.int64`

Comment: Working fine on Python2.7.6 without specifying dtype. Maybe new version of numpy handles it? Has it got to do with 32 bit Operating system by any chance?

Comment: @MYGz Of course. ;) See what `np.array([32, 33]).dtype` prints. And of course, it's possible to install a 32 bit Python on a 64 bit system.

Comment: @MYGz I'm not sure. I've tested it with Python 2.7.9 64-bit, numpy 1.9.0 on Windows 10 64-bit and can reproduce the behavior OP describes.

Comment: Interesting. I guess there's an argument to make `int32` the default type to maintain backwards compatibility. But I don't have a 64 bit machine, and I don't use Windows, so I'll shut up. ;)

Comment: If I specify `dtype=np.int32` then I can reproduce it. With a warning `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app`

Answer (score 3):

It is because when using numpy the numbers given will have a certain size, for example a 32 or 64 bit int. These will overflow in the given calculations, and give negative numbers.

Try making them floats, it should help:

```
print 2**np.array([32., 33.])
```