# Trouble with generating graph from function in python

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib

I want to generate a line graph of temperature versus power and have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temps = np.arange(288, 314, 1)

sigma = 5.67e-8 #Stefan's constant, units = W m^-2 K^-4
T0 = 298 #ambient T, 25 degrees
emissivity = 0.96
A = (np.pi * 309)/80000 #total surface area of chameleon

def SB(T):
    power = A * sigma * emissivity * (T**4 - T0**4)
    return power

power = SB(temps)

plt.plot(temps, power)
plt.xlabel("Temperature (K)")
plt.ylabel("Power (W $m^{-2}$)")
plt.title("Net Power Radiated vs T")
plt.xlim(288, 314)
plt.ylim(0, 1.2)
plt.show()
```

The axes are showing but I'm not getting a line, could it be because the function doesn't take values from np.arange? If so how would I fix this? Any help would be appreciated! :D

Rachel

Comment: Hm, I copy-and-pasted your code and it's plotting a line.

Comment: Are you coding in an interactive session? Maybe restart the interpreter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm working in Spyder but have restarted it and tried it in another interpreter as well and it's now saying "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power" :/

Comment: Wait. Are you using Python 2?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yeah Python 2.7 I think, not clued up on the big differences between the two haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a funny error. First thing, you don't see the line, because it's outside the `ylim` range. Delete the code line which sets the ylim, and you'll see the line.

However the line shows negative values - which is strange, since power should be positive and the formulas are correct.
The reason for that is that the input temperature array `temps` is an `int32` array. This array to the power of four will give negative values, since the numbers are simply too big.

A solution to use a **floating point array** instead. Either use

`temps = np.arange(288., 314., 1)`

or

`temps = np.arange(288, 314, 1).astype(np.float32)`

---

This is reproduced with python 2.7 and numpy 1.12 on windows 8 64bit. The reason for this strange behaviour is seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine): *"In Microsoft C, even on a 64 bit system, the size of the long int data type is 32 bits."*.

Comment: Ah, I think that might be it. On my system, `temp` is dtype('int64'). This depends on whatever `C int` is on your system.

Comment: Any idea why that would be different? Is it python version, numpy version, operating system?

Comment: It depends on your system architecture (for me, I'm on x86_64)

Comment: And actually, will depend on your OS, unfortunately. But it is whatever a C `long` is on your sytem.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine) provides the answer: *"In Microsoft C, even on a 64 bit system, the size of the long int data type is 32 bits."*.

Comment: Ahh thank you everyone, using a floating point array has solved it :D

Comment: @Rachel If this solves your issue, consider [accepting] the answer, such that it will not stay in the unsolved list forever.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks just done it, site newbie sorry!