# Unexpected 32-bit integer overflow in pandas/numpy int64 (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, integer-overflow

Let me start with the example code:

```
import numpy
from pandas import DataFrame

a = DataFrame({"nums": [2233, -23160, -43608]})

a.nums = numpy.int64(a.nums)

print(a.nums ** 2)
print((a.nums ** 2).sum())
```

On my local machine, and other devs' machines, this works as expected and prints out:

```
0       4986289
1     536385600
2    1901657664
Name: nums, dtype: int64
2443029553
```

However, on our production server, we get:

```
0       4986289
1     536385600
2    1901657664
Name: nums, dtype: int64
-1851937743
```

Which is 32-bit integer overflow, despite it being an int64.

The production server is using the same versions of python, numpy, pandas, etc. It's a `64-bit Windows Server 2012` OS and everything reports 64-bit (e.g. `python --version`, `sys.maxsize`, `plastform.architecture`).

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Why don't you use regular Python integers that are capable of representing arbitrarily large numbers?

Comment: We were depending on numpy's infinity calculation when you div by zero. Regardless, this is a workaround. The real issue here is that our dev and prod environments aren't behaving identically.

Comment: @ForceBru: They're slow, bulky, and cause weird breakages if you try to use object arrays full of integer objects.

Comment: Does one of the machines have `bottleneck` installed?

Comment: Might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine

Comment: What is the output of `print((a.nums.values**2).sum(dtype=np.int64))`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser the correct value (2443029553)! So why would sum default to int32 (perhaps like the post ayhan mentioned) on the prod server but then use the actual data type locally.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, the prod server has bottleneck installed. I'll try removing it and see what if it works.

Comment: @user2357112 That did it! How'd you know there was a bug in bottleneck?

Comment: @SeanKramer: I just started digging through the code and wound up in bottleneck. I think bottleneck is mishandling `numpy.int64` on platforms where a C long is 32-bit, and Pandas is getting a check wrong in its attempts to compensate for bottleneck's error.

Comment: It looks like there's a [Github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15453) about this on the Pandas issue tracker. I'm pretty sure they should have checked itemsize==8 instead of itemsize<8; bottleneck should be fine for itemsize<8.

Comment: @user2357112 Not sure about the proper etiquette, but if you want to post that finding as an answer, I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: There's also a [Github issue](https://github.com/kwgoodman/bottleneck/issues/163) on the Bottleneck issue tracker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the `bottleneck` library, which Pandas uses if it's installed. In some circumstances, `bottleneck.nansum` incorrectly has 32-bit overflow behavior when called on 64-bit input.

I believe this is due to `bottleneck` [using `PyInt_FromLong`](https://github.com/kwgoodman/bottleneck/blob/master/bottleneck/src/reduce_template.c#L121) even when `long` is 32-bit. I'm not sure why that even compiles, actually. There's an issue report on the [bottleneck issue tracker](https://github.com/kwgoodman/bottleneck/issues/163), not yet fixed, as well as an issue report on the [Pandas issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15453), where they tried to compensate for Bottleneck's issue (but I think they turned off Bottleneck when it does work instead of when it doesn't).