# OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two date fields in my DataFrame, and I tried to subtract them go get the interval.

```
df_t['trans_delivery_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_t['trans_delivery_date'])
df_t['trans_initiated_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_t['trans_initiated_date'])
df_t['days'] = df_t['trans_delivery_date'] - df_t['trans_initiated_date']
```

I ran the above code but got

```
a OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition
```

But I can run something like

```
t = df_t['trans_delivery_date'][0:100] - df_t['trans_initiated_date'][0:100]
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: look on the following discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526490/3700626

Comment: @LiorCohen Hi, thanks for the reply. But it not fixed yet even now. :(