# Python & Pandas - pd.Series difference between int32 and int64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I'm starting to learn python, numpy and panda's and I have a really basic question, about sizes.

Please see the next code blocks:

**1. Length: 6, dtype: int64**

```
# create a Series from a dict
pd.Series({key: value for key, value in zip('abcdef', range(6))})
```

vs.

**2. Length: 6, dtype: int32**

```
# but why does this generate a smaller integer size???
pd.Series(range(6), index=list('abcdef'))
```

**Question**
So I think when you put a list, numpy array, dictionary etc. in the pd.Series you will get int64 but when you put just the range(6) in the pd.Series you will get int32. Can someone please make this a little bit clear to me?

Sorry for the very basic question.

@Edit : I'm using Pandas version 0.20.1 and Numpy 1.12.1

Comment: What is your python, numpy and OS versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're semantically different in that in the first version you pass a dict with a single scalar value so the dtype becomes `int64`, for the second, you pass a `range` which can be trvially converted to a numpy array and this is `int32`:

```
In[57]:
np.array(range(6)).dtype

Out[57]: dtype('int32')
```

So the construction of the pandas `series`involves a dtype matching in the first instance and none for the second because it's convertible to a numpy array and numpy has determined that `int32` is preferred in this case

**update**

It looks like this is dependant on your `numpy` version and maybe `pandas` version.
I'm running python 3.6, numpy 1.12.1 and pandas 0.20.3 and I get the above result. I'm also running Windows 7 64-bit

@jeremycg is running pandas `0.19.2` and `numpy` 1.11.2 and observes the same result whilst @coldspeed is running `numpy` 1.13.1 and observes `int64`.

The takeaway from this that the `dtype` will largely be determined by what `numpy` does.

I believe that this [line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/83436af8ae1ccad49b7ceac7471c060d823d10ab/pandas/core/series.py#L2994) is what is called when we pass `range` in this case.

```
subarr = np.array(arr, dtype=object, copy=copy)
```

The returned type is determined by `numpy` and OS, in my case windows has defined a C Long as being 32-bits. See related: [numpy array dtype is coming as int32 by default in a windows 10 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine)

Comment: I got both the code output int64 dtype? Does it depend on pandas version

Comment: I'm using `0.20.3`

Comment: `np.array(list(range(6))).dtype` return int64 in my machine.

Comment: @EdChum What numpy version are you running?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 and numpy 1.12.1 all 64-bit

Comment: That's probably the reason. My numpy is 1.13.1 and I'm also getting Bharath's results.

Comment: pandas 0.19.2 and numpy 1.11.2 gives me int32, like @EdChum and the OP

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ surprised this behaviour has changed, but essentially `pandas` will apply `np.array` on the passed in data if it's trivial so the `dtype` is derived from this

Comment: @EdChum can you add the version of libraries in your answer.

Comment: I think this is an OS issue rather than package version. Are you by any chance on Windows?

Comment: I'm running windows 7 64-bit

Comment: This must be the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine

Comment: @ayhan that is probably the reason, should we mark as dupe?

Comment: I think this still has to do with how pandas decides which data type to use so I'd say not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @ayhan, I believe that pandas will try to call the `np.array` ctor on the passed in data if it's iterable or array-like so the dtype will come from `numpy`. in the first case, the default will be `int64` for scalar types passed in this form

Comment: @ayhan I think that this line: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/83436af8ae1ccad49b7ceac7471c060d823d10ab/pandas/core/series.py#L2994 is what is eventually called in this case

Comment: Yes it seems a numpy array is still constructed but dtype decision is not on numpy's part.

Comment: @ayhan I'd expect that once we have numpy arrays and the dtype is not mixed that the dtype will just be passed straight through, I'm trying to search through the code to find anything explicit but it seems to make a Singleblockmanager with the array and then call `NDFrame.__init__` where it will just make a `copy`