# scipy.signal.correlate output is os dependent

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, operating-system

In my code I am using `scipy.signal.correlate` with 1D arrays but it gives me a different result on Windows 11 and on Ubuntu.

The Linux's result should be the right one, since, after some further calculations, it is realistic.

Following the path of the variables it seems that the culprit is `multiarray.correlate`, since the value of all the variables is equal for the 2 OSs until that call in `numeric.py`

Some specifications: it uses mode `full` and method `auto`, it ends up using the method `direct` and so, calling `np.convolve` and then `multiarray.correlate`.

Why is this happening and how can I get the same result across OSs?

Comment: Can you include sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: @NickODell I understood where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to `scipy.signal.correlate` or `multiarray.correlate`, but the fact is that in Windows numpy uses `numpy.int32`, instead, in linux it chooses correctly the type based on the architecture and, in this case, it chooses `numpy.int64`. This leds to an overflow during the calculation of cross-correlation.

Pay attention that this is not written in numpy's documentation.

Sources:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9464

[numpy array dtype is coming as int32 by default in a windows 10 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/numpy-array-dtype-is-coming-as-int32-by-default-in-a-windows-10-64-bit-machine)