Why am I getting a negative answer for positive inputs?
import numpy as np

# Python lists
arr1 = list(range(1_000_000))
arr2 = list(range(1_000_000, 2_000_000))

# Numpy arrays
arr1_np = np.array(arr1).reshape(1, -1)
arr2_np = np.array(arr2).reshape(-1, 1)

print(np.dot(arr1_np, arr2_np))
# >>> [[-1942957984]]

I was simply calculating the dot product.
When I tried it with a for loop, I got the correct answer, but with np.dot(), it is returning an incorrect (negative) integer.
Why is the result negative?

Images of code/data are not acceptable, please provide a [mre]

Does this answer your question? Integer overflow in numpy arrays

Python 3.12.2 with numpy 1.26.4 does not produce that result on MacOS 14.4.1 (M2)

Depending on your system (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278590/), the default integer type of Numpy will be np.int32 rather than np.int64, leading to overflow with the given values (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow: "If the variable has a signed integer type, … integer overflow can cause the value to wrap and become negative"). The problem can be solved by writing np.array(arr1, dtype=np.int64) and np.array(arr2, dtype=np.int64), providing enough bits for larger values.

@simon In the future, please don't transcribe images for the OP.

@Daedalus I am sorry, I was not aware of this discussion.
