# How to skip Error: field larger than field limit (131072) when using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Loading a 5GB csv file using the following code crashes my pc.

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('file.csv',error_bad_lines=False,encoding='latin1',engine='python')
```

However, it seems that this code is able to deal with "field larger than field limit" issue as in the log I get messages such as:

```
Skipping line 1435768: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

I tried to overcome my pc limitations by using chunks:

```
a=pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv', error_bad_lines=False,encoding='latin1',engine='python',chunksize=10000):
    a = pd.concat([a, chunk], ignore_index=True)
```

But this code ignores `"error_bad_lines=False"` as it stops with the following error message:

```
Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

I also tried to read only part of the file, but again error lines are not being skipped:

```
a = pd.read_csv('file.csv', error_bad_lines=False,encoding='latin1',engine='python',skiprows=0, nrows=1000000)
```

results in :

```
Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this problem? I'd like to skip these problematic lines.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063936/csv-error-field-larger-than-field-limit-131072)

Comment: Thanks @Gigioz but this doesn't help as they are not using pandas. I'd also like to skip these rows rather than find a way to load them.

Comment: The duplicate has an answer which discusses how to solve this in Pandas, too.