# Python3: from_buffer_copy to ctypes Structure fails: Buffer size too small

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, pack

I have this class with a 20 byte long ctypes structure:

```
class IP(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = True
    _fields_ = [
        ("_ihl",            c_ubyte, 4),
        ("version",         c_ubyte, 4),
        ("tos",             c_ubyte),
        ("len",             c_ushort),
        ("id",              c_ushort),
        ("offset",          c_ushort),
        ("ttl",             c_ubyte),
        ("protocol_num",    c_ubyte),
        ("sum",             c_ushort),
        ("src",             c_ulong),
        ("dst",             c_ulong)
    ]
    
    def __new__(self, socket_buffer=None):
        return self.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)
```

If I create a new instance with

```
IP(raw_buffer[0:20])
```

i get this error: "Buffer size too small (20 instead of at least 28 bytes)"

If I set *pack* to False, he tries to copy into a 32 bytes structure.

Why is my 20 bytes structure aligned to 28 or 32 bytes? How can I disable this?

Comment: Ok, I think the datatype c_ulong is 64bit and not 32bit anymore

Comment: [\[SO\]: \_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517228/4788546).

Comment: Is there a way to find the byte size of the Structure automatically?

Comment: Can't we do something like `IP(raw_buffer[:sizeof(IP)])`?

Answer (score 0):

ctypes.c_ulong is 64bit, like in C on a 64bit system. So I changed the type to c_uint32 and now it works.

Comment: 64-bit Linux long is 8 bytes.  64-bit Windows long is 4 bytes.