# Why integers do not have size limit in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In python 3, there is no limit on the value of integers, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3).

This does have an interesting side effect with `numpy`, where depending on the integer value, you might get an object or an integer.

```
np.array(int('9'*3)).dtype
# int64

np.array(int('9'*38)).dtype
# object

np.array(2**64-1).dtype
# uint64
```

Can someone explain to me why python 3 does not have a limit on integer size, and how do they do it (under the hood).

Comment: Interesting question, though I get the same behaviour with `Python 2.7.10` (and `numpy 1.13.1`); this does not seem to be a `Python 3` thing.

Comment: I suppose, based on the answer below, if you try `type(2**200)` you should see `long` in python 2, but in python 3 it stays `int`?

Comment: Yes, right, but the `numpy` part is the same I get exact output as you.

Comment: np.iinfo(np.int64)
Out[24]: iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be that there was an `int` type and a `long` type, and values were automatically promoted from `int` to `long` when they got too large (or too small) for `int` to hold them anymore. `long` used as many bytes as is necessary to hold the value at the cost of some performance.

It was possible, however, to have a `long` that could have been an `int`, and there was special literal syntax for `long` values. That is, `0L` was zero as a `long`, whereas `0` was zero as an `int`. These values were equal, but still of different types.

In Python 3, these two types were unified. There is only one type, but its internal representation uses either a machine integer (32-bit or 64-bit depending on version of Python) or an arbitrary-length integer (like `long`) as needed.