# max() fails in python2 -> python3 conversion with `>` not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

While converting from python 2.x -> python 3.x, I found this change in the behavior of the built-in `max` function. I didn't find it documented in any of the standard locations for migration issues.
https://eev.ee/blog/2016/07/31/python-faq-how-do-i-port-to-python-3/
http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

How do I fix this?

Python 2.x:

```
In [1]: max([None, None, None])
In [2]:
```

Python 3.x:

```
In [3]: max([None, None, None])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-f82c85b9875c> in <module>()
----> 1 max([None, None, None])

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: I answered my own "question" (see below), which is supposed to be explicitly encouraged in order to help others.

Comment: @Shankari: Yes, answering your own question is allowed, but I still don't see anything that looks like a question in the "question" part of this post.

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26575183/7207392) interesting.

Comment: I can change the question to be "I got this error, it is not listed in the FAQs, what do I do?". It seems a bit lame to me, but I can do it if it makes people happier.

Comment: @jwodder If it is not a question, how can it have an answer? ;-)

Comment: @Shankari Formulate the question in a way as it probably would be entered here or in Google by someone to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: there is no backwards compatible `max`, but it is arguable that trying to find the max of `None` doesn't really make sense.

The entries that I was comparing were timestamps, and I knew that they would never be negative. So I changed my code to return `0` instead of `None`, so the `max` turned to `max([0,0,0])` which worked.

If you can't make such guarantees about your data, you could return `-sys.maxsize` instead.

```
In [7]: max([-sys.maxsize, -sys.maxsize, -sys.maxsize])
Out[7]: -9223372036854775807
```

Note `sys.maxsize` not `sys.maxint`, which is a documented change.
[What is sys.maxint in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3#13795777)

Answer (score -1):

None represent the absence of a value 
in Python3 shows the error message ,because you dont search the largest item in arguments list of type NoneType