# Python sum and numpy sum giving different results

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sum

I am using Python 3 with Google Colaboratory or the Coursera notebooks platform. I presume the problem would be the same with a local installation.

```
import numpy as np
def sum_numpy(N):
    return np.sum(np.arange(N)**2)

def sum_python(N):
    return sum([i**2 for i in range(N)])
```

sum_numpy(10**8) outputs 662921401752298880, and sum_python(10**8) outputs 333333328333333350000000

These functions give the same results with smaller numbers. For example, they both output 332833500 with 10**3.

Why don't they output the same result with 10**8 ? In theory, integers have no maximum in Python3.

Comment: Numpy integers have a limited size (`int64`), while Python integers can be long.  Look at `np.iinfo('int64')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3