# How to store large integer value in value of key: value pairs of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary of character keys and integer values. I want to store arbitrarily large integers as values of my keys. What is the maximum integer I can store as a value of my key in the dictionary? Is it possible to define the datatype of the dictionary when we initialize it?
For example in C, we do `map<string, long long int>`. What should I do to declare the same dictionary in python?

For example, in the following code, my value will grow immensely for many keys.

```
 for w in words:
     ngrams_w = self.word_to_ngrams(w)
        for n in ngrams_w:
            if n in lookup_table:
                lookup_table[n] = lookup_table[n] + 1
            else:
                lookup_table[n] = 1
     return lookup_table
```

Now I have so many words in my corpus, resulting in too many tri-grams. So, Will the values in my lookup table be able to hold the immensely large integers?

Comment: did you even try anything or just come here to ask?

Comment: Use `sys.maxint` returns **The largest positive integer supported by Python’s regular integer type**.

Comment: @SuperStew, I am storing the counts of letter [tri-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram) in such dictionary. Now my corpus is really large, so value of counts will of course will be very high. So, when I do this on large corpus, the final dictionary I get has all the garbage keys/values. So I was wondering if there is any way to store these large counts in my dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum and Minimum values for ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Comment: @MikePatel it would be best if you posted your code, or a simplified version that exhibits the same behavior

Comment: @SuperStew, posted the code, have a look

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you try that and you got some kind of error?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes, my lookup table looks good for smaller number of documents, i.e. smaller number of words, but when I do this on like 20000 documents, my dictionary keys turn garbage characters, like chinese characters and hindi characters. In a way, I lost all of my keys on doing this on large number of words.

Comment: @Ch3steR _"Use sys.maxint returns The largest positive integer supported by Python’s regular integer type."_ - Nope, it returns `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'maxint'` ;)

Comment: @marcelm look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3 in python 3 `sys.maxint` is replaced by `sys.maxsize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python integers can get arbitrarily large - the amount of bytes they can take up is limited only by the available memory. As a result, you can store very large integers in dicts, just like any other type of variable.

Also note that python's types are behind the scenes. The same `dict` can use almost anything as a key, and anything as a corresponding value. You don't need to declare it in advance.

For example:

```
large_dict = {
   'a': 2**99**2,
   'b': 3**99**2,
   'c': 4**66**3,
   'd': 5,
}

print(large_dict['a'])
# 24830616513292456149616454036974739771820938966442197939419359658089567202400780743905571137028486156486036903513607264042124719153572110201314197883546916952215606391372422139042592773840794323335212159700095246665013394384789465765464293679828325113232950453141468484569985222217035575296458501452872186378717438026640856834533121910412608973480242085881672164719912544082874072107422434390554486837170594217552352179217838815153995983301946373496587090616156896354994345352377952726227907079690576457293694283595586693944067261016834086680506973471228878547284373711902581003346534526356682248040411471279547066667078693613059243075566078841931213128462480543351921983621089668275721435948101887626265184182951445127840725828830209648532962314294583129458462587616879683621002666459872557839185108646816817833525155517060333482860732993614665277625489415502061774379920496929429602780585502167079135606858316403456987934488806952870800041077801533837170751376374861251329800483795256882616805854878581164361680226869833419669385928257122731195573904839938024027782370149377710658645650280419249518679276644090004956974913792951678647959778713113374754349884308332520403967474904860378939613020574276565212696855826404212709820546399167642334178336428555942563152453083892489382421641854517289230831100263608004179956903465008511600241582320500793382331980382057875456793451053160479393167189744446997815108094874623772314046414880967888630771591139242793679368373241262303020403503806741495927267535782756256226464827679171453103936982984219779689528492725634758390287762884938541414982295293195059435820985171981953652126800809143528930914867233895403413631144957773050572055247562723249843368842707168818290935719822151262157837630513192298577647355462098479363787742148415773842359155842482339588691450667863720967596151398289089712023294064255959682719606426598201025203109875583565132643670912933398263577545142697715765285834571917043394759092957857788427530930354248022105571235052694964834870559303479169142265964947215835534331232659231738844605321566863791868404356910674470711233474169254178106049934124965008926126859691353260188518891725702238011978956872340932416194028852429366663313267993063866935339039988538965602564065890425970977641916796977494816019907846068887159081996367805130377827078940214763737954464021880895504378918548182271578043448659561293769460226209756884091241789271212624443566823618854822556818054950921281495213677124939344997301596883289597036555187701021490864067003001042353911716339896584757966357696031609808169050800581900702426733604379398309018563404211559969917703040652231206637777868534421416141767113165973592413599591681134708842927135950028572565259146431359982767414698579766187600152269764793150959658673104646366308004593390529802053032008317417654941763892718192450423219923744313363894743858416682079171193877076995395458797611449453319718948222265568320631084026777091936418337638425034752
```

These should qualify as 'arbitrarily large integers', given that trying to print them overflows the size of my terminal window, and `large_dict['c']` displays fine despite consuming about six times StackOverflow's character limit. Note that things might break when you try to convert them to `float`ing point numbers, because those have a precision limit.

---

Python does support 'type hinting', where you can imply the type of a variable, but it doesn't actually affect anything you can do with the code. Regardless, here's how you would notate this:

```
# need to import Dict to type-hint about it
from typing import Dict

# hint that large_dict should use strings as keys and ints as values
# note that a 'character' is just a 1-length string, as far as python is concerned
# note also that this will not stop someone from putting a non-string in as a key, 
#   or a non-int in as a value
large_dict: Dict[str, int] = {
    ...
}
```

Comment: From your answer, it seems that I can store any integer I want to store in my dictionary values, but I don't know what goes wrong when I run above code on very large corpus, like corpus of billions of words. In that case, the letter trigram counts should go to a trillion at max, so, it should work, but I don't know what's wrong in my code? I think there should be some other bug, so I should better look at the code again.

Comment: _In that case, the letter trigram counts should go to a trillion at max, so, it should work, but I don't know what's wrong in my code? I think there should be some other bug, so I should better look at the code again._ I'm not Green Cloak Guide, but yes, the size of the numbers is probably not the issue.