# Dealing with -0 values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For some reason, my data reduction for a fits image has given me -0 values, which I would like to set to 0.

I've attempted to use:

```
my_array[~numpy.isfinite(my_array)] = 0
```

All I would like to do is set the -0 values in the corrfact_um2_ext1 array to 0. Just to keep everything in the same format, as I think this may cause a problem in subsequent data reduction steps.

But this just deals with NaN values and sets them to 0. So, I'm halfway there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to eliminate the extra minus sign when rounding negative numbers towards zero in numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782038/how-to-eliminate-the-extra-minus-sign-when-rounding-negative-numbers-towards-zer)

Comment: How did you manage to even get -0?

Comment: I don't even know! :) I used scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding 0.0 to each floating point number should fix this:

```
a = np.array([-0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0])
Out[1]: array([-0.,  0.,  1., -1.]

a += 0.0
a
Out[2]: array([ 0.,  0.,  1., -1.])
```

But note:

```
np.array(-0.) == np.array(+0.)
Out[3]: True
```

Does this solve your problem?