# Sparse DataArray Xarray search

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

Using DataArray objects in xarray what is the best way to find all cells that have values != 0.

For example in pandas I would do

```
df.loc[df.col1 > 0]
```

My specific example I'm trying to look at 3 dimensional brain imaging data.

```
first_image_xarray.shape
(140, 140, 96)
dims = ['x','y','z']
```

Looking at the documentation for [xarray.DataArray.where](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html#xarray-dataarray-where) it seems I want something like this:

```
first_image_xarray.where(first_image_xarray.y + first_image_xarray.x  > 0,drop = True)[:,0,0]
```

But I still get arrays with zeros.

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 140)>
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.,  0., -0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

Also - a side question - why are there some negative zeros? Are these values rounded and -0. is actually equal to something like -0.009876 or something?

Comment: If working with very Sparse Matrix I suggest you read about how to work with Sparse Matrix. In particular you can read about `libsvm` data representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(Answer to main question)**

You are almost there. However, a slight syntax difference makes a big difference here. On one hand, here is the solution to filter `>0` values using a **"value-based"** mask.

```
# if you want to DROP values which do not suffice a mask condition
first_image_xarray[:,0,0].where(first_image_xarray[:,0,0] > 0, drop=True)
```

or

```
# if you want to KEEP values which do not suffice a mask condition as nan
first_image_xarray[:,0,0].where(first_image_xarray[:,0,0] > 0, np.nan)
```

On the other hand, the reason why your attempt did not work as you hoped is because with `first_image_xarray.x`, it is referring to the **index** of elements in the array (in `x` direction) rather than referring to the **value** of the elements. Thus only the 1st element of your output should be `nan` instead of `0` because it only does not suffice the mask condition in slice `[:,0,0]`. Yes, you were creating an **"index-based"** mask.

**The following small experiment (hopefully) articulates this critical difference.**

Suppose we have `DataArray` which consists of only `0` and `1` (dimension is aligned with the original post (OP) of the question `(140,140,96)`). Firstly let's mask it based on **index** as OP did:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(0)
# create a DataArray which randomly contains 0 or 1 values
a = xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(0, 2, 140*140*96).reshape((140, 140, 96)), dims=('x', 'y', 'z'))


# with this "index-based" mask, only elements where index of both x and y are 0 are replaced by nan
a.where(a.x + a.y > 0, drop=True)[:,0,0]

Out:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 140)>
array([ nan,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,
         1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
         1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,
         1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,
         1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,
         0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

With the mask above, only the element where **index** of both `x` and `y` are `0` turns in to `nan` and the rest has not been changed or dropped at all.

In contrast, the proposed solution masks the `DataArray` based on the **values** of `DataArray` elements.

```
# with this "value-based" mask, all the values which do not suffice the mask condition are dropped
a[:,0,0].where(a[:,0,0] > 0, drop=True)

Out:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 65)>
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

This successfully dropped all the values which do not suffice a mask condition based on the **values** of `DataArray` elements.

---

**(Answer to side question)**

As for the origin of `-0` and `0` in `DataArray`, rounded values from negative or positive side towards `0` would be the possibility: A related discussion was done here [How to eliminate the extra minus sign when rounding negative numbers towards zero in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782038/how-to-eliminate-the-extra-minus-sign-when-rounding-negative-numbers-towards-zer) The below is a tiny example of this case.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

xr_array = xr.DataArray([-0.1, 0.1])

# you can use either xr.DataArray.round() or np.round() for rounding values of DataArray

xr.DataArray.round(xr_array)

Out:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2)>
array([-0.,  0.])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0

np.round(xr_array)

Out:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2)>
array([-0.,  0.])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
```

As a side note, the other possibility for getting `-0` in NumPy array can be `numpy.set_printoptions(precision=0)`, which hides below decimal point like below (but I know this is not the case this time since you are using `DataArray`):

```
import numpy as np

# default value is precision=8 in ver1.15
np.set_printoptions(precision=0)

np.array([-0.1, 0.1])

Out:
array([-0.,  0.])
```

Anyway, My best guess is that the conversion to `-0` should be manual and intentional rather than automatic in data preparation & pre-processing phase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Marking as correct - wanted to make sure you got the bounty. I'll try it later today. And for the '-0 rounding' your explanation makes total sense. What would I Google to find out why or how they're automatically being rounded. What I mean is: is numpy rounding them or xarray?

Comment: @Liam Hanninen I added more context to the 2nd half. I cannot conclude whether it is numpy or xarray to round them (since both are possibilities), but my best guess is that the rounding were done intentionally during the data pre-processing phase.