# Weird result of floor division in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floor-division

I stumbled upon a floor division result of a np.float32 or np.float64 , which I do not understand

I'm using numpy 1.15.4 in Python 3.6.7

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.float32(0)//1
-0.0
```

I know, that i can workaround by abs() and such, but why am I getting a "-0.0" instead of "0.0" in the first place??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083431/6361531

Comment: @ScottBoston I suggest you to flag it as duplicate instead of just adding the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [negative zero in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083401/negative-zero-in-python)

Comment: @DDS I am not 100% sure this addresses OP's concerns.

Comment: @DDS I don't know, that does not seem to be the same question. I don't see how that would explain how "normal" 0 divided by a positive number yields negative zero. I don't think IEEE 754 mandates (or even allows) that.

Comment: @DDS the link doesn't explain the fact that the vanilla Python equivalent `0.0//1 == 0.0` instead of `-0.0`.

Comment: @ScottBoston It is related, but I think it doesn't explain why `(+0.0) // 1 == -0.0`... especially considering it is something that happens with NumPy but not with Python floating point values.

Comment: For discussion about `numpy` negative zero, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782038/how-to-eliminate-the-extra-minus-sign-when-rounding-negative-numbers-towards-zer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that numpy uses the divmod function to compute the floor division and the line causing this is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src#L668):

```c
/* if div is zero ensure correct sign */
floordiv = (a / b > 0) ? 0.0@c@ : -0.0@c@;
```

Example:

```py
>>> a = np.zeros(1)
>>> b = 1
>>> np.where(a/b > 0, 0.0, -0.0)
array([-0.])
```

Python's `divmod` function seems to handle this correctly, so they must be using different algorithms:

```
>>> divmod(0.0,1)
(0.0, 0.0)
>>> divmod(-0.0,1)
(-0.0, 0.0)
```

I looked into this a bit more and here is how python's divmod works for floating point numbers when div is zero ([link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6d43f6f081023b680d9db4542d19b9e382149f0a/Objects/floatobject.c#L618)):

```c
/* div is zero - get the same sign as the true quotient */
floordiv = copysign(0.0, vx / wx); /* zero w/ sign of vx/wx */
```

and `copysign()` is defined as:

```
double
copysign(double x, double y)
{
    /* use atan2 to distinguish -0. from 0. */
    if (y > 0. || (y == 0. && atan2(y, -1.) > 0.)) {
        return fabs(x);
    } else {
        return -fabs(x);
    }
}
```

so the reason python is able to get this right and numpy isn't is that python uses `atan2()` to distinguish between `-0.0` and `+0.0`.

**Update**: This issue will be fixed in the 1.17.0 release of numpy. You can see the release notes [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.17.0-notes.rst).