# Replace -0 with NoDataValue in GDAL gdal_calc.py

Tags: gdal

I have a bunch of .img terrain files. To make sure the nodata value is consistent before layering them, I'm using this:

```
gdal_calc.py -A /path/infile.img --outfile=/path/outfile.img --calc="A*(A>=-1361)" --NoDataValue=-32768
```

That takes any non-sane value (the lowest elevation in the world is -1360) or anything currently set at the nodata value of -32768 and sets it to -32768.

However, some of the files have areas where the data is -0, which messes up the layering.

How can I include the -0 values in this: `--calc="A*(A>=-1361)"`, so they get set to the new nodata value of -32768?

Basically `--calc="A*(A>=-1361 | A='-0')"` (which fails with invalid syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26786119/410074) describes floating point behaviour with negative zeroes.

Specifically, `y+=0` should be sufficient to remove the negative zeros. This will likely require two passes of `gdal_calc.py`

Comment: another pass of gdal_calc does it:
gdal_calc -A temp.tif --outfile=temp_2.tif --calc="A + 0." --NoDataValue=-32768