# numpy array multiply 10 got wrong result

Tags: python, numpy

I got a very wired test for python2.7 numpy array. Please look at this code.

```
import numpy as np
times = np.arange(5., 85, 0.1)
print times
times = np.array(times * 10, dtype=np.int)
print times
```

the original `times` should be `[5.0 ~ 84.9]`. After multiply 10, it should become `[50 ~ 849]`, but result is like this:

`[ 50  51  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66
  67  68  69  70  71  72 ... ]`
There are two `51` between `50` and `52`

Comment: This is basically a floating point problem. `(times * 10)[2]`  is `51.999999999999993`. If you cast it as int, it will return 51, not 52.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that your third entry isn't exactly `52.0` but `51.999999999999993` (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)). Truncating that value therefore results in `51`.

The correct way would be to first round the values. (As pointed out in [Safest way to convert float to integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387715/3872370) all small enough integer numbers can be exactly expressed as a float.) You therefore have to calculate: `times = np.array(np.round(times * 10), dtype=np.int)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I think for multiply 10, we can use + 0.5, but how about multiply an variable, not only 10?
I want to make sure the result must not same in nearby numbers if the original array not same.

Comment: Adding 0.5 works for all positive numbers, since it "converts" a truncation to a rounding operation. For example 0.999 gets 1.499, which truncated results in 1. However if the small decrease in performance is no problem using `np.round` (as in my updated answer) is the better option (and also working for negative numbers).