# Is it possible to convert the result from float to integer in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple script with a single function but i want to convert the result from float to an integer data type. Is it possible in this case?

This is the script

```
def minutes_to_hours(minutes):
    hours=minutes/60
    return hours
def seconds_to_hours(seconds):
    hours=seconds/int(3600)
    return hours
print(minutes_to_hours(100))
print(seconds_to_hours(int(3600)))
```

And the result is

```
1.6666666666666667
1.0
```

The result is correct but as you can see i want to change the data type from float to an integer (`1` rather than `1.0`), is it possible?

Related to python functions.

Comment: Isn't` `int(value)` what you want?

Comment: yeah, the value should be an integer 1, rather than 1.0, is it possible? Please correct my script if any changes required.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: In your specific case, you could use integer division `//`instead of floating point division `/`, but the answer given by @iBug is more generic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safest way to convert float to integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387655/safest-way-to-convert-float-to-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's builtin function does the job:

```
>>> print(int(seconds_to_hours(int(3600)))
1
>>> print(type(int(seconds_to_hours(int(3600))))
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

Note that your code `hours=seconds/int(3600)` does not generate an integer, as opposed to C. If you want to do integer division, use double slash:

```
hours=seconds//int(3600)
#            ^^
```

If you want to convert whatever into `int` without knowing whether it can, use this function:

```
def try_int(v)
    try:
        return int(v)
    except ValueError:
        return v
```

Then you'll be able to convert only those that are able to be converted into `int` into `int`.

Comment: it's probably worth mentioning that `int()` trunctuates the value (and `round` should be used if the floating point value should be rounded)

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type cast your result.

e.g.

```
a = 1.000
b = int(a)  #typeCasting to int
print(b)    # or return (int(return Value)) in your code
```