# There is error showing when running an datatype problem in python. Error is like: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23.5'"

Tags: python, types

```
>>>int(str(23))  
>>>23
```

But When putting float value inside str() this is showing an error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23.5'

```
>>>int(str(23.5))
>>>ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23.5'
```

Comment: What result were you expecting? `23.5`? That's not an integer. `23`? `int` won't parse a string *and* truncate - it'd cause more bugs than it's worth.

Comment: When you convert 23.5 to str, `.` is considered as dot not point

Comment: This isn't python, it's maths. Is 23.5 an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, `23.5` is not a valid integer.

If you'd like to convert the number to a float, write

```
float(str(23.5))
```

If you're just interested in the integer part:

```
int(float(str(23.5)))
```

though there are caveats to that: [Safest way to convert float to integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387655/safest-way-to-convert-float-to-integer-in-python)